# I want to sign output DLLs of my project but those projects could work on different machines

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to sign output DLLs of my projects.

I have created **.pfx** file on my machine (Project **properties.Signing.Sign** the assembly with *Visual studio 2008* on `.NET 3.5 CE` ) and able to sign DLLs but when I push my code to repository (as every project has **.pfx** file is included ) but  my server is not able to build project it gives error as

> [“Import Key file”]

I am getting **same** error when I tried to run this project on **different** machine.

How can I create project with **.pfx** signing which can run on every developer machine without importing **.pfx** file.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b33fc15d-d125-44b1-846a-7f461f3b1504/sign-assembly-with-pfx-certificate?forum=winformssetup)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create project with .pfx signing which can run on every developer machine without importing .pfx file.

Visual Studio allows you to perform both *ClickOnce* and *Strong Name* signing by specifying a file path to the .PFX file (ideally within your solution hierarchy or somewhere common to all DEV/CI machines) **without** requiring you to import the certificate into the *Windows Certificate Store* beforehand.

On the **Signing** page:

a) for ClickOnce, tick **Sign the ClickOnce manifests**, choose **Select From File...** and select your projects **.PFX**

b) for Strong Naming, tick **Sign the Assembly** then click **Choose a strong name key file**, then click **Browse** and select your **.PFX**

It's advisable to put the .PFX into your solution's hierarachy and use relative paths.

Comment: In my solution Sign the ClickOnce manifests is always disabled and security and publish tab is absent.

Comment: @Tejashri I didn't mention **Security** and **Publish** tabs, it's not relevant for you if you aren't using _ClickOnce_.

Comment: but ClickOnce manifests is disabled and I don't know from where I can enable it. I am using VS2008.. Please help me on this

Comment: @Tejashri Just ignore the ClickOnce aspect of my answer.  Refer to part _**(b)**_.

Comment: I have use option B but when I tried to check in code my server or other developer could not able to import .pfx file and getting error as [“Import Key file”]

Comment: @Tejashri That's a **new** question.  Post it on SO.  I would appreciate an upvote or that you accept my answer if appropriate

Comment: Thanks for reply MickyD. I have stated same question above as I am getting  [“Import Key file”]  error on different machine  when i tried run my code but, same code is successfully build on my machine. Please help me on this, why i am getting this message and how I can run .pfx certificate on different machine without  any manual interaction (like importing certificate).

Comment: @Tejashri You don't need to import anything.  Please follow my instructions